# Простейший запрос AJAX к серверу

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте буквально недавно приступил к изучению технологии AJAX и в этом деле я очень "Зелёный" пример я брал от [сюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest). Серверная написана на ASP.NET MVC4, в примере же написана на Node.js. Дело в том что сервер не присылает ответ, а отладчик JS в хроме выдаёт ошибку 404 (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)). Как отправить запрос к серверу что бы он вернул ответ в XML?

```
//представление index
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var LoadXml = function () {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "~/Home/SayHello", false);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        };
    }
</script>

<button onclick="LoadXml()">загрузить Xml</button>

//Контроллер Home
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SayHello()
        {
            return new XMLResult("Hello. I'm your first AJAX request");
        }

    }

//Объект генерирующий XML (его объект создаётся выше в SayHello())
    public class XMLResult : ActionResult
    {
        private string text;
        public XMLResult(string text)
        {
            this.text = text;
        }
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" +
                "<text>\r\n" + this.text + "\r\n</text>";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

Как отправить корректный запрос к серверу?

Comment: "~/Home/SayHello" полный путь подставьте

Comment: @Konst, пробовал, одно и то же.

Comment: обработчик ошибки добавьте. и проверьте логи IIS, что там сервер то отвечает на ваш запрос

Comment: @Konst, простите, скиньте пожалуйста статью как это сделать.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest обратите внимание на onerror . примеры найдёте ,я думаю сами

Comment: рассматрите вариант использования $.ajax({})

Answer (score 1):

Нужно прописать правильный URI вот тут

```
xhr.open("GET", "~/Home/SayHello", false);
```

Comment: Он вроде правильно, символ тильды сам механизм ASP.NET заменит на домен, далее идёт имя контроллера и за ним действие контроллера. Если вставить в атрибут href тэга a, то всё работает и я увижу надпись "Hello. I'm your first AJAX request" в браузере

Comment: asp.net в этом случае не работает

Comment: @Konst пробовал, одно и то же. Заменил на `xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:49247/Home/SayHello", false);` и ничего не изменилось

Comment: http:// надо писать и опубликуйте приложение на локальный сервер IIS, а не на эмулятор

Comment: @Konst Visual studio сама запускает его локально на IIS сервере, ну так в книге по asp.net написано

Comment: там 2 варианта запуска, посмотрите в свойствах солюшена

Answer (score 1):

Чего-то смотрел, смотрел я. И кажется, единственное, что надо поправить это JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var LoadXml = function () {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "@Url.Action("SayHello")", true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

Сделаю небольшую ремарку по данному коду.
`@Url.Action("SayHello")` - более корректный подход к получению URL нужного Action. Т.к. если Вы вдруг измените роутинг, то Вам не придется переписывать все ссылки.

`xhr.open("GET", "@Url.Action("SayHello")", true);` последний параметр говорит о том, что вызов должен быть асинхронным (не знаю как у Вас, а у меня хром уже не позволяет делать синхронные вызовы).

Ну и не забываем отправить сам запрос `xhr.send();`